# Dataset for queries that are questions or others

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, nlp

I am looking for a dataset of queries that are posted in live chats or service providing chats. I want to test my API for tagging a query that is entered by the customer as a question or not a question. I am not able to find a suitable dataset that include some samples like:

1. where should I go to eat food.
2. Book a cab which serves food.

The first statement is a question where as second is not.These are the types of queries that a customer might use with out it being grammatically correct.
I need a dataset consisting of such data which are used in spoken English.

Comment: see this answer https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/6613/1511

Answer (score 1):

The [NPS Chat Corpus](http://faculty.nps.edu/cmartell/NPSChat.htm) is a sample of messages from various online chat platforms tagged by part of speech at the word and passage level.  Excerpts from the dataset description:

> Description of the NPS Chat Corpus
>
> The NPS Chat Corpus, Release 1.0 consists of 10,567 posts out of
>   approximately 500,000 posts we have gathered from various online chat
>   services in accordance with their terms of service. Future releases
>   will contain more posts from more domains. New releases will be
>   announced and described at
>
> http://faculty.nps.edu/cmartell/NPSChat.htm.
>
> The posts included in Release 1.0 have been:
>
> 1) Hand privacy masked;
>   2) Part-of-speech tagged; and
>   3) Dialogue-act tagged.

...

> The dialogue-act tags are Accept, Bye, Clarify, Continuer, Emotion,
>   Emphasis, Greet, No Answer, Other, Reject, Statement, System,
>   Wh-Question, Yes Answer, Yes/No Question. (See [2] and [3], below.)
>
> Sample Post
>
> Here is a sample post from the corpus:

```
<Post class="whQuestion" user="11-08-teensUser117">whats balck and white and red all over?<terminals>
               <t pos="WP" word="whats"/>
               <t pos="^JJ" word="balck"/>
               <t pos="CC" word="and"/>
               <t pos="JJ" word="white"/>
               <t pos="CC" word="and"/>
               <t pos="JJ" word="red"/>
               <t pos="DT" word="all"/>
               <t pos="IN" word="over"/>
               <t pos="." word="?"/>
</terminals> </Post>
```

**Citation**

> Eric N. Forsyth and Craig H. Martell, "Lexical and Discourse Analysis
>   of Online Chat Dialog," Proceedings of the First IEEE International
>   Conference on Semantic Computing (ICSC 2007), pp. 19-26, September
>   2007. http://faculty.nps.edu/cmartell/NPSChat.htm.