# Customer Support Interactions data?

Tags: data-request

I need to answer some of the following questions:

- What is the average amount of time taken to close a customer issue?
- What is the average length of chat for a particular segment of the complaint?  (For example: Kindle, delivery, etc can be different segments for Amazon)
- Predicting the next possible complaint, and in which category.

I know this data would be highly varying from company to company. But, open data of any customer support team would do.

I think this need multiple datasets.  If all of them are not possible to get, a subset would also do, which can answer atleast one or more of the questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most open data these days is coming from governments and some non-profits... and I have not seen any data such as the ones you're asking for.

Somewhat related data may include 311 call requests, requests for assistance from police, and building code enforcement/complaint cases. In case it's helpful, I have included a few examples below:

- City of San Francisco, CA - 311 Case Data: https://data.sfgov.org/City-Infrastructure/Case-Data-from-San-Francisco-311-SF311-/vw6y-z8j6
- City of West Sacramento, CA - Service Requests: https://data.cityofwestsacramento.org/dataset/Service-Requests/qdyy-nmpt
- City of Renton, WA - Police Case Reports: https://data.rentonwa.gov/Public-Safety/Police-Case-Reports/nhic-8vdu
- City of Los Angeles, CA - Building and Code Enforcement Cases: https://data.lacity.org/A-Safe-City/Building-and-Safety-Code-Enforcement-Case/2uz8-3tj3
- City of Austin, TX - Code Complaints Events: https://data.austintexas.gov/Government/Austin-Code-Complaint-Case-Events/afwp-v695