# Looking for customer service chat dataset

Tags: data-request, social-media, internet, data-portal

I am looking for specific customer support chat dataset or question answers dataset, for example network support, hardware, software support, ticket remedy chats etc. I need to mine the data for specific contents.

Looking for data in text format:

```
message: hi
response: hello
```

Comment: Related: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6612/customer-support-interactions-data and https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/dataset-for-queries-that-are-questions-or-others

Comment: not much of help, i am looking for chat logs or may be question answers dataset.

Comment: is this a duplicate of this question? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6056/1511